# How do I do a complete uninstall of RVM, Ruby and Rails on a mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I having all kinds of different problems with the above mentioned and I would like to start fresh (short of re-installing the OS) - how do I remove ruby, rails and rvm???

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove *~/.rvm* and reinstall RVM it :

```
curl https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer | bash -s stable
```